# ¿Como puedo obtener la linea en la que se ejecuta una funcion?

Tags: php

Quiero hacer un sistema en donde las cosas que almacene en una variable, las muestre en un panel especifico y dentro de la informacion que quiero mostrar ahi, sea la linea en la que ejecute esa funcion:

Funcion que almacena la informacion que quiero desplegar en pantalla

```
function get_vardump($var)
{
    $dump = array(
        "var" => $var, 
         "line" => $lineEjecution
    );
    $GLOBALS['vardump'] = $dump;
}
```

Funcion que retorna un html con las variables almacenadas
Es en esta funcion en la que quiero agregar la linea en la que se ejecuto

```
function read_vardump()
{
    if(get_debug() === true)
    {
        if(isset($GLOBALS['vardump']))
        {
            $vars = $GLOBALS['vardump'];
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }

        $html = '<div id="debug-panel">';
        if(!empty($vars))
        {
            foreach ($vars as $value) 
            {
                $html .= 'Line '.$value['line'].': '.$value['var'].'<br>';
            }   
        }
        $html .= '</div>';
        return $html;
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

La idea es, que la $lineEjecution, sea la linea en la que se ejecuto el get_vardump()
PD: get_debug() es una funcion que me muestra si la app esta en modo de debug o no, solo eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta utilizar la siguiente función de php

```
$bt = debug_backtrace();
$debugger= array_shift($bt);

echo $debugger['line'];
```